# Javascript  - Swap layer and grouping

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, configuration, swap

I am trying to make a "simple" product-configurator thingie ...
Right now I have it working with drop-downs.

you can view it here (I made a shirt example - but actually it should be for other products as well):

http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/9t4f4/15/

As you can see, it works with drop downs, and the obvious problem is that it is not ADDING the feature, but REPLACING it (for each option group).

I tried with append() - and you can see it commented out in the code , but in that case, it will not remove (and will append forever - resulting in 50 divs ..

My questions are :

1. how can I make it work also with radio buttons and checkboxes ?
2. how to ADD the "option" if it is from another group, and how to "remove" it when it is from the same group ?
3. How to make the division into "options groups" work automatically ?

(I know that theoretically I could make a div for each option and a function for each - but the configuration will have about 60 of these - so I need some solid logic in ONE function)

**EDIT I :**

I have just noticed another bug :
If one selects all the options of the same level (e.g. - option #3 from all 3 dropdowns) and then returns to another group dropdown - and select again the same level - it will not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full answer would be here :

http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/9t4f4/23/

Answer (score -1):

using checkbox will be appropriate solution for the problem add group them together using some class

```
<input type="checkbox" class="option" value="9">
```

now you can write your simple jquery to toggle the src image

```
$('.option').change(function() {
    if(this.checked){
     $('#prod-image').attr('src', data[value].img);
    }else{
     $('#prod-image').attr('src', "");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. but I am sorry, I fail to understand how this will resolve the problem of ADDING layers and not just changing them. changing the 'src' attribute will always just change the image , no ? can you maybe show an example of what you mean ??